# Combining functions for auto attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I have some script which attaches and sends a file based on some incoming e-mail rules which works perfectly.

```
Sub AddAttachment(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Templates\test upload file.oft")
    Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
    myAttachments.Add "C:\TEST\150520ABCDE.txt"
myItem.Send
End Sub
```

Trouble I have is the attachment file name "150520ABCDE.txt" changes daily. "150520" being the date.

I therefore have some more script which should assign the correct file name based on date.

```
Function LPad (str, pad, length)
    LPad = String(length - Len(str), pad) & str
End Function

y = Year(Now)
m = Month(Now)
d = Day(Now)

f = "C:\Test\" & Mid(y, 3, 2) & LPad(m, "0", 2) & LPad(d, "0", 2) & "ABCDE.txt"

myAttachments.Add f
```

My question is how do I tie them both together in to one script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I actually would do instead is:

```
Sub AddAttachment(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
 Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Templates\test upload file.oft")
Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
myAttachments.Add "C:\TEST\" & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & "ABCDE.txt"
myItem.Send
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the following line of code in the script:

> Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Why do you need to create a new Outlook Application instance in the code? Instead, you may use the Application property in VBA or just use the passed argument to retrieve the required properties.

```
Sub AddAttachment(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
 Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Templates\test upload file.oft")
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
 myAttachments.Add "C:\Test\" & Mid(Year(Now), 3, 2) & LPad(Month(Now), "0", 2) & LPad(Day(Now), "0", 2) & "ABCDE.txt"
 ' or simply use the Format method
 ' myAttachments.Add "C:\TEST\" & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & "ABCDE.txt"
 myItem.Send
End Sub

Function LPad (str, pad, length)
  LPad = String(length - Len(str), pad) & str
End Function
```

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.